# WinForm TreeNode expand does not Expand the node after running the application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am going through a list to add node to my TreeView. I want to expand the first 5 root nodes and collapse the others. So after adding a node I am calling `TreeNode.Expand()` to have it expanded, but it does not work. Here's the code snippet:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
     var parentNode = treeViewTamsha.Nodes.Add($"Node {i}");

       if (i < 3)
       {
         parentNode.Expand();
       }
       else
       {
            parentNode.Collapse();
       }

       for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
       {
            var childNode = treeViewTamsha.Nodes[treeViewTamsha.Nodes.Count - 1].Nodes
                    .Add($"Child node: {i}.{j}");
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the given snippet is you have to call `.Expand()` **AFTER** you are done adding children to the node. So, I just had to move the `.Expand()` call after the nested `for` loop

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    var parentNode = treeViewTamsha.Nodes.Add($"Node {i}");

    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        var childNode = treeViewTamsha.Nodes[treeViewTamsha.Nodes.Count - 1].Nodes
            .Add($"Child node: {i}.{j}");
    }

//***************** Moved this block after the nested for loop *****************/
    if (i < 3)
    {
        parentNode.Expand();
    }
    else
    {
        parentNode.Collapse();
    }
}
```